# File Deletion from Desktop

Tags: windows-vista, desktop, flv

I recently downloaded a video file in FLV format. However at present I am unable to copy, move, or even delete the file.

Is there any way to remove it? AVG doesnt show any infections, File Shredder hangs when I try to use it to remove the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), maybe the file is locked by another program.

Sometimes, you just need to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista and 7 have some random bugs with file operations. One of them I have is if I copy or delete, the icon sometimes stays even when it is no longer there.

Simply click an empty space on your desktop then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the screen.

Comment: thnx wil bt nthing lyk it my case

Answer (score 0):

u can try safe mode, i believe that it will be deleted in this way..

Safe Mode:
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/safe-mode-windows-7.htm